# How to auto calculate the html table using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, calculated-columns

Can someone or anybody help me on how to auto calculate total price in the table? Please see the image below:

[image: Please see the image below]

Here's my code (I will included only the code that I used in the Image):

HTML:

```
<div class="col-12">
  <div class="col drop">
    <table name="services">
      <tr name="services">
        <td>
          <select class="form-control serv" name="txt-service" id="txt-service">    //dynamic services (from database)
            <option value="" readonly>--- Select Service ---</option>
               <?php include "include/connect.php";
                 $sql="SELECT service_id,services,price FROM tbl_serviceoffered";
                    foreach ($con->query($sql) as $row){
                     echo "<option value=$row[service_id] data-price=$row[price] data-service=$row[services]>$row[services]</option>";
                    }
                     echo "</select>";
                ?>
         </td>
         <td><input type="hidden" style="text-align:right" class="form-control" name="service" id="showservice" readonly></td>
         <td><input type="text" style="text-align:right" class="form-control" name="price" id="showprice" readonly></td>
         <td><input type="text" style="text-align:right" class="form-control" name="item_total" id="item_total"></td>
         <td><button class="btn btn-primary" name="add">Add</button></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
   </div>
</div>  

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped" name="transactions" id="transactions">
    <thead>
     <th></th>
     <th style="text-align:center">Service Name</th>
     <th style="text-align:center">Service Price</th>
     <th style="text-align:center">Service Total</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     </tbody>
   </table>
    <td colspan="2" class="tr">&nbsp;</td>
      <div class="text-right">
        <tr>
         <td><b>Total</b></td>
         <td colspan="2" style="text-align: right"><input class="form-control input-sm" style="width:300px;margin-left:auto" style="text-align:right; font-weight:bold" class="form-control" name="grand_total" id="grand_total" placeholder="Total"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cash Tendered</td>
           <td colspan="2" style="text-align: right"><input class="form-control input-sm" style="width:300px;margin-left:auto" type="text" name="cashtendered" placeholder="Cash Tendered"></td>
         </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Change</td>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align: right"><input class="form-control input-sm" style="width:300px;margin-left:auto" type="text" name="change" placeholder="Change"></td>
       </div> &nbsp;           
     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="text-right">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-icon icon-right" name="btnSaveTransaction" id="btnSaveTransaction"><i class="fas fa-file-invoice"></i> Process Payment</a>
   </div>
```

JS:

```
var id = 1; 


 /*Assigning id and class for tr and td tags for separation.*/
    $("button[name=add]").click(function() {
        var newid = id++; 
    $("table[name=transactions]").append('<tr id="'+newid+'">\n\
        <td style="text-align:center;"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0);" id="remove">Remove</a></td>\n\
        <td width="100px" style="display:none;">' +newid+ '</td>\n\
        <td style="text-align:center; display:none;" class="num'+newid+'">' + $("#txt-transact_num").val() + '</td>\n\
        <td style="text-align:center; display:none;" class="date'+newid+'">' + $("#txt-transact_date").val() + '</td>\n\
        <td style="text-align:center; display:none;" class="patientid'+newid+'">' + $("#txt-patient_id").val() + '</td>\n\
        <td style="text-align:center;" class="serv'+newid+'">' + $("#showservice").val() + '</td>\n\
        <td style="text-align:center; display:none;" class="servid'+newid+'">' + $(".serv option:selected").val() + '</td>\n\
        <td style="text-align:right;" class="price'+newid+'">₱' + $("#showprice").val() + '</td>\n\
        <td style="text-align:right;" name="txt" class="totalprice'+newid+'">₱' + $("#item_total").val() + '</td>');

        $("#txt-service").val("");
        $("#showprice").val("");
        $("#item_total").val("0.00");

        calculateSum();
    });

    function calculateSum() {
        var sum = 0;
        //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
        $("tbody").each(function () {
            //add only if the value is number
            if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }
        });
        //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
        $("#grand_total").val(sum.toFixed(2));
    }

    $("#transactions").on('click', '#remove', function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        calculateSum();
    });
```

As you can see, in the image above, when I add or pick some services that shows the total each of them, the textbox "*total*" fetch **0.00** only.

> ```
> I'm still beginner in this programming language. I hope everyone can help me for our Capstone Project. Thank you!
> ```

Comment: ids are meant to be unique. `id="remove">Remove</a>` is probably going to cause you problems in some browsers. You should use a class selector instead. E.G `class="remove-link">Remove</a>`

Comment: `$("tbody").each(function () {` this is iterating through `<tr>` DOM elements. These `<tr>` will not have a `this.value` (value). You need to select the price inside the `<td>` inside each `<tr>`

Comment: @bassxzero can you give an example for that?

Comment: If you create a https://jsfiddle.net/ with your example code, and post it with your question then I will fix it.